# If $f$ is measurable, can we write $f = r \cdot \exp(i\varphi)$ for $r, \varphi$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, polar-coordinates

It is well known, that if we have an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and a continuous curve $c \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $c(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$, then there exist continuous functions $r \colon [a,b] \to (0,\infty)$ and $\varphi \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $$c(t) = r(t)(\cos(\varphi(t)), \sin(\varphi(t)))$$ holds for all $t \in [a,b]$. This motivates the following question:

If $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measure space and $f \colon X \to \mathbb{C}$ is measurable, do there exist measurable functions $r \colon X \to [0, \infty)$ (note that $r$ is allowed to be 0) and $\varphi \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $$f(x) = r(x)(\cos(\varphi(x)) + i \sin(\varphi(x)))$$ I know that $\varphi$ (if existent) certainly will not be unique and that $r$ can indeed be found quite easily by $$r(x) = |f(x)|$$ So the main struggle is with finding $\varphi$.

> Can we prove that there always exists such a measurable $\varphi$?

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the statement holds for simple functions $f = \sum \alpha_k \chi_{A_k}$, by simply setting $r = |f|$ and $\varphi = \sum \varphi_k \chi_{A_k}$, where the $\varphi_k \in \mathbb{R}$ are chosen such that $f(x) = r(x) \exp(i\varphi_k)$, since then by construction $$f = r \cdot \exp(i\varphi)$$ Now it is clear, that if we have an arbitrary measurable function $f$, then we can approximate $f$ by simple function, thus by what we have seen before, we may find a sequence of simple functions $\{\varphi_n\}$ such that $$r(x)\exp(i\varphi_n(x)) \to f(x)$$ for all $x \in X$. However, this does not guarantee, that there exists some $\varphi \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $\varphi_n(x) \to \varphi(x)$ and $r(x)\exp(i\varphi(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: a measurable function is a limit of simple functions and for these you do have a measurable $\varphi$. Just make sure that $\varphi$ stays between $-\pi$ and strictly $\pi$ so you end up with a simply converging sequence of measurable functions. Then you can pass to the limit and keep measuraibility.

Comment: Oh I see, so basically if $f=\sum \alpha_k \chi_{A_k}$, then we can find $\varphi_k \in \mathbb{R}$ so that if we let $$\varphi = \sum \varphi_k \chi_{A_k}$$ then $$r(x)(\cos(\varphi(x)), \sin(\varphi(x))) = r(x)(\cos(\varphi_k), \sin(\varphi_k)) = \alpha_k=f(x)$$ for all $x \in A_k$, right?

Comment: @studenr_du_05 Can you elaborate on why it is important to assume $\varphi$ having values solely in $(-\pi, \pi]$? Why could that destroy measurability?

Comment: Yes. Just chose the $\varphi_k$ in an interval of length $2\pi$, open at one end an closed at the other so they converge pointwise.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to pass to the limit. Approximate the fonction $1$ by a sequences of simple $f_n$ all equal to $1$. Then $f_n=e^{i\varphi_n}$ with $\varphi_n=2n\pi$.

Comment: How do you know a sequence like $\varphi_n = \sum_k \varphi_{n_k} \chi_{A_{n_k}}$ with all $\varphi_{n_k} \in (-\pi, \pi]$ will converge to some $\varphi$ if we only know that $$r(x) (\cos(\varphi_n(x)), \sin(\varphi_n(x))) \to f(x) $$ ?

Comment: I'm sure you can figure that out by yourself

Comment: @student_du_05 Are you sure it is true, that if you have a bounded sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}_n$, $f_n \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$, then there always exists a subsequence that is pointwise convergent to some measurable $f$? I mean it is clear that the sequences $\{f_n(x)\}_n$ have convergent subsequences for all $x \in X$ by Bolzano-Weierstrass, however it's not like I could do a diagonal argument because I don't know how big $X$ is..

Comment: Taking the $\varphi_n$ in $]-\pi, \pi]$ isn't abound boundedness. It's about restricting $e^{ix}$ to a set of values of $x$ where it is injective, which allows you to argue that since $e^{i\varphi_n(x)}$ converges, so does $\varphi_n(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases} \arccos\left(\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{f(x)}{\lvert f(x) \rvert}\right)\right) &\text{if $f(x)\neq 0$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f(x))\geq 0$,} \\ 
-\arccos\left(\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{f(x)}{\lvert f(x) \rvert}\right)\right) &\text{if $f(x)\neq 0$ and $\mathrm{Im}(f(x))< 0$,} \\ 
0 &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Then $\varphi$ is measurable as a composition of measurable functions, and one has $f(x)=r(x) e^{i\varphi(x)}$.

Comment: If $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|}$ then isn't $\sin(\arccos(\text{Re}(g))) = \sqrt{1-\text{Re}(g)^2} = |\text{Im}(g)|$ and therefore $r(x)\exp(i\varphi(x)) = \text{Re}(f)(x) + i |\text{Im}(f)(x)|$, or am I mistaken?

Comment: So basically this would accomplish a representation of the form $$f(x) = r(x)\exp(i\varphi(x))\chi_{\{\text{Im}(f) \geq 0\}} + r(x) \exp(-i\varphi(x)) \chi_{\{\text{Im}(f) < 0\}}$$

Comment: Indeed, there was an issue when $\mathrm{Im}(f(x))<0$. I corrected it, and it should work now.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot :)